# I need to create a function in the controller to show a specific view with filename determined by the database. - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a system where there is a default page and 4 models, these models can be changed, the name of the file corresponding to the model is in the database, that's when my problems started, because I can not put the variable that determines the filename in return view (), although the variable is within the same function, I know the problem is not the variable, it returns the expected value, but the laravel doesn't recognize it the way I'm trying.

**controller**

```
public function searchByName($name)
{
    $company = Company::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
    $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();
    $home_cp = DB::table('personalities')->select('index_company')->where('name', $name)->first();  
    $index_company = view('company.base.$home_cp');
    return view('company.base.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'index_company'));
}
```

**view**

```
@if(isset($personality))
     {{$index_company}}
@else
        @include('company.base.default')
@endif;
```

**erro**

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [company.base.$home_cp] not found.
```

the problem here is that it says a page was not found, because the file '$ home_cp' does not exist, ie it does not treat '$ home_cp' as a variable, so it does not return what I need in this case the file name.

Note that the problem is with the controller, not the preview. If you go to the preview and find nothing, it will show you the default file.

what would be the best way to solve this or what would be the right way to do it (if any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `double` quotes to parse the variable instead of single quotes

```
$index_company = view('company.base.$home_cp');
```

Should be

```
$index_company = view("company.base.$home_cp");
```

Comment: now this has happened: ErrorException
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Check the contents of `$home_cp`. You need to convert it into a string.

Comment: It should be `$home_cp->index_company`

Comment: everything worked out on the controller! the sad thing is that it went wrong in the view

Comment: {{$home_cp}} - Return: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I had home_cp in head, you are very good, thanks for the help!

Comment: just a doubt, not wanting to abuse his time, it is normal he returns in the source code ";" with the file empty? how can you get that out?

Comment: You might want to check if `$home_cp` is empty and have check that condition in both view and controller.

Comment: oops already solved! never mind.  that was it here:
 @endif;   | 
thank you again.